# Picking the commits to merge with master

Tags: git, rebase

Say I have a buggy function in my master branch:

```
def foo(x):
   return 1/x
git commit -a -m "foo is created"
```

I create a new branch called `bug` to debug it.

```
git checkout -b bug
```

I create some print statements for debugging, and commit:

```
def foo(x):
    print x
    return 1/x
git commit -a -m "print statements are added for debugging"
```

Finally the bug is fixed.

```
def foo(x):
    print x
    if x == 0:
       return None
    return 1/x
git commit -a -m "foo bug is fixed"
```

Now I would like to rebase the second commit on the `bug` branch with `master`, but I don't like to add the print statements (i.e. the first commit), so I use the interactive rebase as follows:

```
git rebase -i master

drop b2296f0 printing
pick 62beaa8 fixed
```

and only select the second commit (i.e. bugfix), However I get this conflict:

```
def foo(x):
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
    print x
    if x == 0:
        return None
>>>>>>> 62beaa8... fixed
    return 1/x
```

Is there a way to have git get the correct version, without me manually deleting all debug print statements?

Comment: `git cherry-pick`

Comment: you need to cherry-pick it, not rebase it

Comment: @Liam I thought the use-case for interactive rebase is to pick and choose the commits?

Comment: No that's cherry **picking**... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your checkout and rebase targets should be the other way around. The rebase command can be articulated with wording to the effect of "unwind from my current position up to the commit specified".

Furthermore, as you'll already be on the feature/bugfix branch you can ignore the checkout and instead just do

`git rebase -i master`

and pick/squash/fixup the desired commits. When done you can then merge in:

`git checkout master
git merge bug`

If instead you want the branch to be preserved in the git tree you can merge in with a specific merge commit (instead of doing a fast-forward):

`git merge --no-ff bug`

Comment: I get this conflict when I try rebase: `def foo(x):
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
 print x
 if x == 0:
  return None
>>>>>>> 62beaa8... fixed
 return 1/x` I was hoping that git would remove the print statements and apply the bugfix.

Comment: I edited the question. I choose pick to the bugfix and drop for the print statement.